# OpenCV 2.3.1 Qt cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK returns same points

Tags: qt, opencv

I 'm using `OpenCV 2.3.1` and `Qt` and i am facing a problem with `cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK`. I am using `oodFeaturesToTrack` and `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK` to track a face that I have previously detected.

```
std::vector<cv::Point2f> Feat;
GrayFrame=FrameBuffer->GetFrame();

cv::goodFeaturesToTrack(GrayFrame,
                        Feat,
                        maxcorners,
                        qualitylevel,
                        mindistance);

while(1){
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> NewFeat;
    std::vector<uchar> status;
    std::vector<float> err;
    GrayFramePrev=GrayFrame.clone();
    GrayFrame=FrameBuffer->GetFrame();

    cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(GrayFramePrev,
                             GrayFrame,
                             Feat,
                             NewFeat, 
                             status,
                             err);

    Feat=NewFeat;
}//while(1)
```

`GrayFrame` takes an image from a buffer where i store the images captured from a webcam both `GrayFrame` and `GrayFramePrev` contain the right image `(GrayFrame -> FrameBuffer[i], GrayFramePrev -> FrameBuffer[i-1])` when they are at c`v::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK` and the Feat parameter contains points from `goodFeaturesToTrack`. But when `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK` is executed it returns via NewFeat the exact same points.

Please tell me what i am doing wrong with the `` `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK ``

### **Solution (For me)**

I used the following parameters and it worked (i probably mixed up Feat and NewFeat also so that was the problem).

```
cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(GreyFramePrev,
                         GreyFrame,
                         Feat,
                         NewFeat,
                         status,
                         err,
                         *WinSize,
                         maxLevel,
                         *TermCrit,
                         derivLamda,
                         LKflags,
                         minEigThreshold);
```

**Parameter values**

```
WinSize= new cv::Size(31,31);
maxLevel=3;
TermCrit= new cv::TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER|CV_TERMCRIT_EPS,20,0.03);
derivLamda=0;
LKflags=0;    
minEigThreshold=0.001;
```